# Some inline assembler questions

Tags: visual-c++, assembly, x86, inline-assembly, cpuid

I already asked similar question here, but I still get some errors, so I hope you could tell me what am I doing wrong. Just know that I know assembler, and I have done several projects in 8051 assembler, and even it is not the same, is close to x86 asm.

There is block of code I tried in VC++ 2010 Express (I am trying to get information from CPUID instruction): `

```
int main()
{
char a[17]; //containing array for the CPUID string
a[16] = '\0'; //null termination for the std::cout
void *b=&a[0]; 
int c=0; //predefined value which need to be loaded into eax before cpuid

_asm
{
    mov eax,c;
    cpuid;
    mov [b],eax;
    mov [b+4],ebx;
    mov [b+8],ecx;
    mov [b+12],edx;
}
std::cout<<a;
}`
```

So, to quick summarize, I tried to create void pointer to the first element of array, and than using indirect addressing just move values from registers. But this approach gives me "stack around b variable is corrupted run-time error" but I don´t know why.

Please help. Thanks. And this is just for study purposes, i know there are functions for CPUID....

EDIT: Also, how can you use direct addressing in x86 VC++ 2010 inline assembler? I mean common syntax for immediate number load in 8051 is `mov src,#number` but in VC++ asm its `mov dest,number` without # sign. So how to tell the compiler you want to access memory cell adress x directly?

Comment: You don't need c at all. Just use 'xor eax,eax' to set eax=0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason your stack is corrupted is because you're storing the value of `eax` in `b`.  Then storing the value of `ebx` at the memory location `b+4`, etc.  The inline assembler syntax `[b+4]` is equivalent to the C++ expression `&(b+4)`, if `b` were a byte pointer.

You can see this if you watch `b` and single-step.  As soon as you execute `mov [b],eax`, the value of `b` changes.

One way to fix the problem is to load the value of `b` into an index register and use indexed addressing:

```
mov edi,[b]
mov [edi],eax
mov [edi+4],ebx
mov [edi+8],ecx
mov [edi+12],edx
```

You don't really need `b` at all, to hold a pointer to `a`.  You can load the index register directly with the `lea` (load effective address) instruction:

```
lea edi,a
mov [edi],eax
... etc ...
```

If you're fiddling with inline assembler, it's a good idea to open the Registers window in the debugger and watch how things change when you're single stepping.

You can also directly address the memory:

```
mov dword ptr a,eax
mov dword ptr a+4,ebx
... etc ...
```

However, direct addressing like that required more code bytes than the indexed addressing in the previous example.

I think the above, with the `lea` (Load Effective Address) instruction and the direct addressing I showed answers your final question.

Answer (score 0):

The advice to open the Registers window in the debugger watch how things change is not going to work in VC++ 2010 Express.

You might be just as surprised as myself to find out that the VC++ 2010 Express is MISSING the registers window. This is especially surprising since stepping in disassembly works.

The only workaround I know is to open a watch window and type the register names in the Name field. Type in EAX EBX ECX EDX ESI EDI EIP ESP EBP EFL and CS DS ES SS FS GS if you want

ST1 ST2 ST3 ST4 ST5 ST6 ST7 also work in the watch window.

You will probably also want to set the Value to Hexadecimal by right clicking in the Watch window and checking Hexadecimal Display.